# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Invalid Request Line Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

Our Linux Docker ASP.NET Core container server logs are getting filled by the following 'Informational' log entries since we've updated from .NET Core 2.0 to .NET Core 2.1 (SDK 2.1.302):

```
INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel|Connection id "0HLFG42JUAORG" bad request 
data: "Invalid request line: 
'CNXN\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x04\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x00M\x0A'" 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Invalid 
request line: 'CNXN\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x04\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x00M\x0A'

INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel|Connection id "0HLFG42JUAORH" bad request 
data: "Invalid request line: 
'CNXN\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x04\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x00M\x0A'" 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Invalid 
request line: 'CNXN\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x04\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x00M\x0A'
```

The connection ID is incrementing by 1 alpha/digit every second or so. The hex doesn't seem translate to anything meaningful (`NUL NUL NUL SOH NUL NUL EOT NUL ESC NUL NUL LF`).

Things we've ruled out:

- It's not originating from WAN/LAN (disabled network access to the
  containers and the entries are still being generated).
- It doesn't occur in our development environment (windows w/ Visual Studio)
- Redeploying the docker container doesn't fix the issue.
- We don't believe it to be an SSL issue since kestrel is configured for http only. We can access the app and it's websockets (SignalR) over https and wss

Comment: *kestrel is configured for http only* maybe that's the problem, something trying to talk to it with HTTPS on port 80? https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1321#issuecomment-274893813

Comment: We've ruled that out by disabled all network connectivity to the container, but it's still appearing.

Comment: Look at a Proxy or Firewall you have set up between your “WebClient” and “WebServer” .   think about the typical browser to server communication lifecycle such as OpenConnection GET – Response Comes back – close Connection.  Look for a firewall or a very common protocol assumption that would be true 90% of the time – but is not true in your case that is failing.  For example – HTTP2.0. The problem is probably below your code in the common Network Lifecycle.  Some Firewalls are stricter by default then you may need – you may have to allow the “bad” command at a proxy or firewall level.

Comment: How confident are you that your Windows Dev infrastructure and containers build process is also working in your LINUX Container Environment.  Do you have a primitive hello world scenario that proves your two environments are building working containers for the full network round trip path in both environments - using .Net Core 2.1  and or 2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with the docker host (debian) and hanging sockets (netstat showing a lot of TIME_WAITs). Changed the app port to a different one and the malformed requests stopped.

A reboot or restart of the docker daemon would probably also fix it, but the uptime of our other containers is vital so we weren't able to test that.

Answer (score 32):

It looks like you're hitting an HTTP endpoint over HTTPS.

Comment: This was the cause in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and in my case solution was in nginx configuration - I had proxy_pass set to https://localhost:4000 instead of http://localhost:4000